# Norm of a 2-by-2 matrix

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, matrix-analysis

> Let $$A = \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & b \\ -b & c \end{pmatrix} \in M_2
> $$ be a contraction, i.e., $\Vert A\Vert\le 1$, and $$\gamma := \frac{b}{\sin\theta}\leq 1$$ Show that there exists $a \in\mathbb{C}$ with $\vert a\vert\leq 1$ such that $c=\gamma^2\cos\theta+(1-\gamma^2)a$.

---

It seems there always exists a point $a$ s.t. $c$can be written as a particular convex combination of $\cos\theta$ and $a$. But now the question is whether this $a$ will be in the unit disc? For that, I gave the following attempts.

**Attempt I**: I was initially trying to show $a\in W(A)$ i.e. numerical range of $A$ which would prove the required thing as $A$ is a contraction. But later I observed that $a$ could not belong to $W(A)$.

**Attempt II**: I tried to find out two vectors $x$ and $y$ with $\Vert x\Vert\le 1$ and $\Vert y \Vert \le 1$ s.t. $\langle Ax, y\rangle=a$ which would prove the required thing as $A$ is a contraction. Here also I observed later that it is not possible.

**Attempt III**: I also tried to show it by contrapositive argument i.e. if $\vert a \vert\ >1$ then there is a vector $x$ with $\Vert x\Vert\le 1$ s.t. $\Vert Ax\Vert >1$ but unfortunately could not get success here also.

Any hint/comment is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1551 Actually here $\gamma$ is a fixed no between 0 and 1 (which also depends on b). As a result whenever $b$ is 0, $\gamma$ has to be 0 (from the relation between b and $\gamma$ which I did not mention before). What I wanted to ask is the following? Let $\gamma$ be fixed no between 0 and 1(dependent on b). Is it possible to get $a$ with $\vert a\vert\leq 1$ s.t. $c=\gamma^2\overline{\lambda}+(1-\gamma^2)a$?

Comment: @user1551 I have edited.